# Why am I obliged to filter the graph URI in a SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, rdf, virtuoso, triplestore, named-graphs

To fetch all the triples from a named graph in my triplestore ([OpenLink Virtuoso v6.1](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/)), I have written the SPARQL query:

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
WHERE {
    GRAPH eg:myGraph {
        ?s ?p ?o.
    }
}
```

But it seems I can't define the graph URI in the GRAPH declaration; the query doesn't return any triples.

If I use an intermediate variable `?g` instead of the URI of my graph, the request works:

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
WHERE {
    FILTER(?g = eg:myGraph).
    GRAPH ?g {
        ?s ?p ?o.
    }
}
```

I don't see the difference between the two queries.

Is my first syntax a wrong query? Is this a subtlety of Virtuoso?

Comment: The two queries are equivalent. I also think the first is more efficient (generally speaking, because it has less variables). It must be a limitation/bug of the Virtuoso SPARQL parser.

Comment: Does `select ... where { values ?g { eg:myGraph } graph ?g { ... } }` work?  That might be more efficient than the filter, and makes it clearer that the value of ?g is supposed to have a predefined value.

Comment: There is the same result as before `graph ?`. I've just seen that my version of virtuoso is the curent default version for debian : virtuoso 6.1 . Perhaps this problem is solved with virtuoso 7?

Comment: SPARQL return an error on `values`. I think that the parser of this version just doesn't apply the curent SPARQL 1.1 specifications.

Comment: You might need Virtuoso 7

Answer (score 0):

you can try to run

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
FROM NAMED eg:myGraph
WHERE {
    GRAPH eg:myGraph {
        ?s ?p ?o.
    }
}
```

or

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
FROM eg:myGraph
WHERE {
        ?s ?p ?o.
    }
```

Comment: Your first command return the right result (without '<' and '>') but second return the entire default graph. As said in the comments of the question, I think it is a problem in the version of virtuoso (unfortunately the last version working on the system I'm working on).

Comment: yea I think that it mainly depends on which triple store you are using... with stardog they both work properly. If eg:myGraph wasn't intended to be a uri but a curie (which it is fairly obvious... I'm going to edit my answer) you don't need the <>